# React array update

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Working on reactJS project, and I know we don't mutate the state (usually i don't but don't know the exact reason) so I just tried some wrong approach even its working correctly.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './test';
import {Home, NotFoundComponent,Contact, Profile} from './test/home'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      list: [42, 33, 68],
    };
  }
 
  onUpdateItem = i => {
    this.state.list[i]++;
    this.setState({
      list: this.state.list,
    })

    // this.setState(state => {
    //   const list = state.list.map((item, j) => {
    //     if (j === i) {
    //       return item + 1;
    //     } else {
    //       return item;
    //     }
    //   });
 
    //   return {
    //     list,
    //   };
    // });
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item}>
              The person is {item} years old.
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => this.onUpdateItem(index)}
              >
                Make me one year older
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default App;
```

```
this.state.list[i]++;
this.setState({
  list: this.state.list,
})
```

what is the problem with when I update the code above instead map method, both give the correct output?

explain to me this behind the scene
[code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-neumann-f78mh)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach unless if your state is `immutable`. But be careful when you're working with reference types. But if you've children which dependent on parent `list`, it doesn't update the children.

Comment: cause both ref type is equal and content only differ so child cant recognizes It correct?

Comment: That's right!!!

Comment: I have created a example here. Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wt5tf4?file=src%2FChild.js

Comment: bro, which react part knows both refs is same so we don't need to update UI, is render() or shoulcomponemtUpdate() life cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason:

When you mutate an array, say `list[i]++` the identity of the array is not changed so `listBefore ==== listAfter`, while you map over the array `listBefore !== listAfter`, when you invoke `setState`, ALL the children component will be invoked again by default even if you put nothing inside `setState`. Because react can not tell if the children update is necessary by default and it is a waste of resources actually.

You can prevent this from happening by telling the Children "Do NOT update" by calling `shouldComponentUpdate` or simply use `PureComponent`.

And the way to tell if updates are necessary is to compare using `===`

In addition, Even if you do not care about performance. you should never do this. It will cause some debuggable bugs in some cases mainly because **the updates in react is NOT synchronized**. I never encounter by the way because I do not even dare to try

Comment: if i update throgh this.state.list.map((value,index)=>{ means childern wont update?

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi the children will ALWAYS update by default even if you call `setState({})` (empty object), you can confirm what I say by putting `console.log` in children

Answer (score 1):

When you update your `state` you should take care of `immutable`.

```
onUpdateItem = i => {
  //this.state.list[i]++;
  //this.setState({
  //  list: this.state.list,
  //})
  this.setState({
    list: this.state.list.map((value,index)=>{
      if(i === index) return value+1;
      return value;
    })
  });
}
```

If you are not maintaining immutable, your app will not work what you expected.

React states are updated follow **life-cycle**.
if without immutability, it means you are breaking the life-cycle.

Comment: I know, what if i am not maintaining immutable?

Comment: He asked why and you told him how